# How to save custom Objects onSaveInstanceState without implementing parcelable

Tags: android, bundle, parcelable

i need to save a custom object that i use in a fragment so it will not be lost when the screen rotates (when the app calls onDestroy and then recalls onCreate)

now the normal way to do so is to implement Parcelable interface and save it to the bundle as a Parcelable object.

that is a very tedious way of doing things.

is there a way to just pass the object along as "putObject" method?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

well searching i found no official way of doing so, so here are two "hacks" i found around the problem:

1)create a class that extends Application class, in it add an arrayList of objects.
inside onSaveInstanceState call:

```
getApplication().getObjectArray().add(YourObject);
```

save the Object index inside the bundle using putInt.

extract it inside the method onReturnestoreInstanceState.

2)my less favorite one:

android automatically saves the states of its views
therefor a way to save an object will be to create a view set its visibility to none so it wont show on the screen and then add each object we want to the view using the methods:

```
view.setTag(key,Object); or view.setTag(Object);
```

now inside onReturnestoreInstanceState get the view and extract the tags.

unfortunately i couldn't find a more simple way of saving an object

hope this one helps you out (in my app i ended up using the first method)

Comment: I won't consider this approach as readable and maintainable, KISS!

Answer (score 3):

You can save your data in fragment, retained during a configuration change like in [example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html).

> Extend the Fragment class and declare references to your stateful
>   objects.

```
public class RetainedFragment extends Fragment {
    // data object we want to retain
    private MyDataObject data;
    // this method is only called once for this fragment
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // retain this fragment
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }
    .. getter and setter
}
```

> Then use FragmentManager to add the fragment to the activity.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private RetainedFragment dataFragment;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ..    
        // find the retained fragment on activity restarts
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        dataFragment = (RetainedFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(“data”);

        // create the fragment and data the first time
        if (dataFragment == null) {
            // add the fragment
            dataFragment = new DataFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(dataFragment, “data”).commit();
        } else { 
            // available dataFragment.getData()
            .. 
           // save data in onDestroy dataFragment.setData(yourData);
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to implement [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) (Faster).

Easier (not efficient) way is to implement [Serializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) and add the object into the bundle as serializable.

Comment: parcelable has to be implemented for each object you pass, if you need to pass a few objects each comprised of  multiple fields or of sub objects you have to do alot of work.

Comment: Agreed. If you need a easier solution, you can implement Serializable interface. Its not efficient though.

Comment: thats why in the end i avoided the problem all together and created the object array in the application class, i use it as an itermediate, since its should be avaliable unless the app was closed, i store the object and then i extract if from there without all the hustle